# What is accumulation and release centre of neurohormones?

Tags: neuroscience, neurology

What is accumulation and release centre of neurohormones?

Is it hypothalamus?

Comment: Have you tried googling it ?

Comment: Incidentally yes.
I just want to be sure whether it is hypothalamus.

Comment: There are many tissues expressing and secreting neuropeptides and hormones. Certainly the hypothalamus and pituitary gland, but there are clusters of enervating through the brsinstem secreting GLP1, a host of enteroendocrine tissues to name a few. Are there some hormones in particular you are interested in?

Answer (score 5):

The [neurohormones](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/410635/neurohormone) in most mammals include oxytocin and vasopressin, both of which are **produced in the hypothalamic region** of the brain and **secreted into the blood by the neurohypophysis (part of the pituitary gland)**.

A second group of neurohormones, called releasing hormones, also originates in the hypothalamus. The members of this group, however, are transmitted within the neural cells to a second locus in the brain, from which they pass in the bloodstream to the **adenohypophysis**, which also is a part of the pituitary gland. There they either stimulate or inhibit the release of the various adenohypophysial hormones.

A third group of neurohormones includes the enkephalins and other endorphins. The endorphins are effective in relieving pain, a property apparently related to their function as neurotransmitters, passing nerve impulses from one neuron to another. Their neurohormonal activity is manifested by their stimulation of the secretion of somatotropin and vasopressin by an indirect process **involving a site (other than the secretory neuron) in the central nervous system.**